# How to use session in JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have stored  the Usertype  in the session. It is printing hello, Admin! when i'm using   <%= session.getAttribute( "Usertype" ) %> but not showing the menu options with

```
<p>hello,  <%= session.getAttribute( "Usertype" ) %></p>

        <c:set scope="session" var="Usertype" value="${param.Usertype}" />

        <c:choose>
             <c:when test="${Usertype == 'Employee'}">
        <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:when>
     <c:when test="${Usertype == 'Manager'}">
        <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="newemployee.jsp">Add New Employeer</a></li>
            <li><a href="retrieve.jsp">Retrieve TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:when>
     <c:when test="${Usertype == 'Admin'}">
         <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="newemployee.jsp">Add New Employeer</a></li>
            <li><a href="retrieve.jsp">Retrieve TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:when>
```

Comment: Do you have a closing tag for _<c:choose>_ ? And use _<c:otherwise>_ for the last test, _<c:choose>_ is the equivalent for the _if-else if-else_ statement.

Comment: @drgPP sorry I have closing tag for <c:choose>... It didn't copy!

Comment: to be sure you are storing correctly the value in your jstl variable, you could print it using `<c:out value="${Usertype}" />` after it declaration.

Comment: thanks for the advice I'll change that.  I'm looking for <c:choose> why its not working. please help me to solve it.

Comment: as @Selvakumar Ponnusamy has mentioned, to retrieve the value from the session using jstl, you have to use `<c:set var="Usertype" value="${sessionScope.Usertype}" />`

Comment: @drgPP +1 for pointing that out! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access like this ${sessionScope.Usertype} to get values from session

Comment: i belive it's `${sessionScope.Usertype}`

Comment: @SelvakumarPonnusamy  thanks a lot! as drgpp pointed that out its working.